# To plot 2 or 3 curves with time on x axis in a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, time, ipython

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import datetime

def graph():
    time,value = np.loadtxt('location_file1.csv',delimiter=',', unpack=True, converter ={0: datetime.datetime(2016,10,12,'%H-%M-%S')}
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot_time(x=time,y=value,fmt=':')
    plt.title('analysis')
    plt.ylabel('Velocity')
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.show()
```

Gives:

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-4d3ced24fa3f>", line 3
    fig = plt.figure()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`I want to plot the information that I have extracted from gps module. It's saved in a csv file consisting of velocity and time. I have the first 2 columns for the first day data and next two columns for the second day. I have to plot multiple curves in a graph. Need help...here is the file: [csv file of 2 days information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9tiu.png)

dont really need the date.so i just gave a random date.i only need time on the x axis...but there is some error in the def of the graph

I am using jupyter Qtconsole 4.1.1
python 2.7.11
IPython 4.0.3

Comment: Don't expect people to write codes for you. Do your own due diligence. Make some effort and post again with your code and error message if you have not succeeded.

Comment: import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import datetime

def graph():
    time,value = np.loadtxt('location_file1.csv',delimiter=',', unpack=True, converter ={0: datetime.datetime(2016,10,12,'%H-%M-%S')}
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot_time(x=time,y=value,fmt=':')
    plt.title('analysis')
    plt.ylabel('Velocity')
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.show()
    
  File "<ipython-input-4-4d3ced24fa3f>", line 3
    fig = plt.figure()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I think you're missing a closing bracket. Top tip with syntax errors: if you get one anywhere near the start of a line, the mistake might actually be on the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthesis at the end of the line:

```
time,value = np.loadtxt('location_file1.csv',delimiter=',', unpack=True, converter ={0: datetime.datetime(2016,10,12,'%H-%M-%S')})
```

, the error appeared in the next line because the interpreter was expecting you to continue whatever instructions you were giving inside the parenthesis.